# Input type and Bias type for basic CNN giving error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I was trying my hand at following along with a guide for making a CNN with pytorch ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/tutorials/pytorch-train-model)). I am not using the CIFAR-10 dataset and have made my own dataset as such. I think that is where the issue is, but I don't know what's up.

Here is my error:

[image]

It sounds silly to say, but I tried following the guide expecting success and instead ran into these errors. I have tried researching a bit online as to any possible solutions and struggled to find any resources which might be helpful to me.

I will also share with you my Dataset class:

```
class ASLDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset): # inheritin from Dataset class
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir="", transform=None):
        self.annotation_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir # root directory of images, leave "" if using the image path column in the __getitem__ method
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotation_df) # return length (numer of rows) of the dataframe

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotation_df.iloc[idx, 1]) #use image path column (index = 1) in csv file
        image = cv2.imread(image_path) # read image by cv2
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert from BGR to RGB for matplotlib
        class_name = self.annotation_df.iloc[idx, 2] # use class name column (index = 2) in csv file
        class_index = self.annotation_df.iloc[idx, 3] # use class index column (index = 3) in csv file
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, class_index #, class_name

train_dataset = ASLDataset('./train.csv') #, train_transform)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)

val_dataset = ASLDataset('./test.csv')  # val.csv
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=num_workers)

classes = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'nothing', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'space', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

And here are the lines which appear in the error code as well as the network from the guide:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=12, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(12)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=12, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(12)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=24, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(24)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=24, out_channels=24, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(24)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(24 * 10 * 10, 10)

    def forward(self, input):
        output = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(input)))
        output = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(output)))
        output = self.pool(output)
        output = F.relu(self.bn4(self.conv4(output)))
        output = F.relu(self.bn5(self.conv5(output)))
        output = output.view(-1, 24 * 10 * 10)
        output = self.fc1(output)

        return output
```

```
def train(num_epochs):
    best_accuracy = 0.0

    # Define your execution device
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print("The model will be running on", device, "device")
    # Convert model parameters and buffers to CPU or Cuda
    model.to(device)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_acc = 0.0

        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader, 0):

            # get the inputs
            images = Variable(images.to(device))
            print(type(labels))
            labels = Variable(labels.to(device))

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # predict classes using images from the training set
            outputs = model(images)
            # compute the loss based on model output and real labels
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
            # backpropagate the loss
            loss.backward()
            # adjust parameters based on the calculated gradients
            optimizer.step()

#Code goes on from here
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, theistic wishes and invocations, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

With further work and some outside assistance I was able to get an answer to this problem. My problem had been partly in my class definitions and how I called some items later in the code. Rather than defining my ASLDataset class with no transforms in `__init__` I should have had the following:

```
class ASLDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset): # inheritin from Dataset class
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir="", transform=transforms.ToTensor()):
        self.annotation_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir # root directory of images, leave "" if using the image path column in the __getitem__ method
        self.transform = transform
        
        ....
```

When I began converting the inputs to tensor I also had to change the way I called returns later. Any time I called images or labels (which is what I renamed class_index to) I had to call them as such:

```
            #Define the device which will be used for processing
            device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

            #Modify both the images and the labels so that they are stored as tensors
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
```

Keep in mind that images and labels were the returns for my ASLDataset class's `__getitem__`:

```
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotation_df.iloc[idx, 1]) #use image path column (index = 1) in csv file
        # image = read_image(image_path)

        print("Got item")

        image = cv2.imread(image_path) # read image by cv2
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert from BGR to RGB for matplotlib
        label = self.annotation_df.iloc[idx, 3]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, label
```